# Changing pixel value based on polygon extent in PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3, extents

I have a raster layer and a polygon layer. Polygon layer is inside of raster layer and it's extent is smaller than raster layer. Some pixels of raster layer inside the polygon have negative value. I want to change the negative values based on maximum pixel value that is inside the polygon in GDAL or PyQGIS. So In first step I must find the max value based on below code:

```
r_lyr = QgsRasterLayer('.../aa.tif', 'Raster')
v_lyr= QgsVectorLayer('../bb.shp','bb',"ogr") 
v_ext = v_lyr.extent()
#(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) = (v_ext.xMinimum(), v_ext.xMaximum(), v_ext.yMinimum(), v_ext.yMaximum())

provider = r_lyr.dataProvider()
r_ext = provider.extent()


rows = r_lyr.height()
cols = r_lyr.width()

block = provider.block(1, v_ext, cols, rows)
lst = []
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        #print (block.value(i,j)),
        lst.append(block.value(i,j))
max_v = max(lst)
```

In second step it is important to get pixels inside the polygon and then change them to maximum value.

In [@xunilk's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192296/how-do-i-change-the-pixel-values-of-raster-data-from-qgis-python-plugin) to [Changing pixel values of raster data from QGIS python plugin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/192296/115) there is a way to change the pixel value but by this answer it is possible to do for full extent of raster layer.

How can I merge my code with @xunilk's code for doing it?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about GDAL then please do that in a separate question so that this one can remain focused on PyQGIS.