# Importing numpy array into QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, numpy

I have some computation on a numpy array and want to display the result in QGIS. So far ok, but loading the result into QGIS fails. Here my code fragment:

```
zData2 = np.subtract(myarray,zData2) #do some computes
output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('',ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)  
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(zData2)   # Writes my array to the raster

newLayer = QgsRasterLayer(output_raster,'my new raster') #this failes...
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(newLayer)
```

Comment: How exactly does it fail?

Comment: arguments did not match any overloaded call: QgsRasterLayer(): too many arguments QgsRasterLayer(QString, QString baseName=QString.null, bool loadDefaultStyleFlag=True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Dataset' QgsRasterLayer(QString, QString, QString, bool loadDefaultStyleFlag=True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Dataset' See log for more details

Comment: QgsRasterLayer is expecting a string corresponding to the path, for example it works with a physical TIFF file. So I guess that is the question, how to do it with a 'MEM' dataset.

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34082/creating-raster-layer-from-numpy-array-using-pyqgis

Comment: The solution I normally use is to create raster file (persists my data) with my calculations and then load it as a QgsRasterLayer.